# How to create an ENUM array column with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I would like to have an array of strings in my PostgreSQL database, and have them be converted to a set of enum objects in my code. This is what I have:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = CurrencyDto.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<CurrencyDto> currencyOptions;
```

But, it tries to fetch it from another table with this error `relation "theme_config_currency_options" does not exist`

I don't want JPA to fetch it from another table. The string representation of my enum objects should be in that column inside an array. My enum
class is `CurrencyDto`.

```
public enum CurrencyDto {
    ALL, //Albania
    AMD, //Armenia
    AZN, //Azerbaijan
    BYN, //Belarus
    BAM, //Bosnia and Herzegovina
    BGN, //Bulgaria
    ...
}
```

How can achieve what I want properly?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add the dependencies required to do the job.
Then you should create DTO class for currency,

```
@Entity
public class Currency {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String title;
}


public enum CurrencyName {
    C1, C2, C3, C4;
}
```

now by using this class you can set the currency name and can fetch the data from the database.

Comment: do I really have to create a currency table just for this? please check my enum class in the question. I just added it.

Comment: Yes, where you are going to get the name of the currency.

Comment: I want to name the currency in my code. I don't want to store currencies in the database. My currencies will not change.

Answer (score 0):

1. entity should be like

```
    @Builder
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "entity_name")
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
    public class EntityName {
    
       @Builder.Default
       @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
       @Type(type = "json")
       private Set<CurrencyDto> currencyOptions = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

2. migration for "EntityName" table

```
currency_options JSONB NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]'::jsonb
```